# Create Oracle Update Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, insert-update, database-trigger

Hi guys first time asking here in Stack Overflow.

So my question is as follows: When a row is inserted into table A reward points need to be calculated and they must be added to an earned points column in table B. We also need to calculate extra points depending on the tier of the Customers in Table B. Table B has a FK that references Table C which contains the attribute I Need so that my calculation for earned points is correct.

Ive managed to compile the following code which basically links Table A and B but I don't know how to get the value I need from table C in order for this to be correct.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER JavierRewards
AFTER INSERT ON Purchases
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE customers
    SET customers.earned_points = customers.earned_points + Round(:New.purchase_amount * 1.5)
    WHERE customers.cust_id = :new.cust_id;
END;
```

Any ideas? First time learning triggers so its a bit frustrating.

Comment: General remark: Don't do too much of this logic in triggers. In the end you may need to do changes without these triggers firing, and you're basically stuck with a lot of business logic hidden away in your database without any ability to control when it fires. If you can't take it out of the database, at least create a stored proc that stores the purchase and updates the customer. I learned that the hard way.

Comment: Its for a homework and after this I have to do procedures lol

Comment: Ah ^.^ In that case it's okay :)

Comment: Any suggestions for this in the meantime?

Comment: Oh, I thought Barbaros Özhan was well on his way answering your question. :-)  And you may support him a bit by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use the following one with an extra select statement :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER JavierRewards
AFTER INSERT ON Purchases
FOR EACH ROW
    v_Extra_Amount TableC.Extra_Amount%type;
BEGIN
   BEGIN
      SELECT c.Extra_Amount 
        INTO v_Extra_Amount
        FROM TableC c 
        JOIN customers s on s.c_ID = c.ID
       WHERE s.cust_id = :new.cust_id;
     EXCEPTION WHEN no_data_found THEN v_Extra_Amount := 0;
   END;

    UPDATE customers s
       SET s.earned_points = s.earned_points + Round(:New.purchase_amount * 1.5) 
                            + (:New.Purchase_amount * v_Extra_Amount)
     WHERE s.cust_id = :new.cust_id;
END;
```

Comment: Hello Barbaros! Table C has a number basically I want to use in my calculation and I don't know how to get it. I need a way to get c.earned points =  c.earned_points + Round(:New.purchase_amount * 1.5) + (:New.Purchase_amount * Extra Amount). Extra amount is a value contained in table C.

Comment: @JavierRuizVelez Hi Javier, I've updated, is that you're looking for..?

Comment: Hello Barbaros just to clear up since I feel Im all over the place trying to explain this: Table B has a FK called Tier_ID which references Rewards_Tier (table C). Table C has an attribute named Extra_Amount which is the one I do not know how to get. For some reason what you wrote me gave me an error.

Comment: Barbaros thank you very very much you have solved over 12 hours of pain. Thank you so much Sir.

Comment: @JavierRuizVelez you're welcome dear friend. Please mark the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Hey Barbaros! I have a question regarding a Procedure Im trying to write. Can you help me with it?

Comment: @JavierRuizVelez Hello Javier, tell me please.

Comment: Barbaros my friend here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53773756/solving-procedure-with-no-parameters

Answer (score 0):

You should consider placing both insert and update actions into some function, because one should use triggers only if it is the last option, imho